# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in php, with mysqli connection

Tags: php, mysql

I am programming a registration for a website and am having trouble with the mysql database, now i got this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/*****/public_html/register.php on line 50

I dont see my own mistake and would be happy if someone of you could find it in my code:

```
<?php


$servername = "*****";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

/*define('DB_HOST', 'mysql.hostinger.de');
define('DB_NAME', 'u544596746_cobra');
define('DB_USER','u544596746_admin');
define('DB_PASSWORD','H6huA7qFRk2v');


$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());*/

function register()
{

    session_start();
    if($_POST["email"]!="" and $_POST["password"]!="" and $_POST["username"]!="" and $_POST["password"]== $_POST["password_confirm"])
    {
         $sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUser`(`UserName`, `Vorname`, `Nachname`, `EMail`, `Geschlecht`, `Geburtsdatum`, `RegestrierungDate`, `Password`, `FKRole`) VALUES ('" .$_POST['username']. "','" . $_POST['vorname']. "','" .$_POST['nachname']. "','" .$_POST['email']. "','" .$_POST['geschlecht']. "','" .$_POST['geburtsdatum']. "',Curdate(),'" .$_POST['password']. "',2)";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        //header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: 404.html');
    }
}
if(isset    ($_POST['submit']))
{
    register();
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: now i get the error: 

Call to a member function query() on a non-object on line 31 but i dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
```

doesn't have a corresponding closing brace.

Comment: wooow, i'm so blind. thx

Comment: Please accept and upvote if this helped ;)

Comment: sure, i can accept in 12 minutes ^^

Comment: now i get the error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object on line 31 but i dont know why

Comment: `$conn` is not within the scope of your function.

Comment: Also, just an FYI, if your original issue is solved and your code has another issue, it's generally a good idea on SO to ask another question.